# Why do we need `rotateToARCamera` in Apple's `Visualizing a Point Cloud Using Scene Depth` sample code?

Tags: ios, graphics, computer-vision, arkit, metal

Sample code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/visualizing_a_point_cloud_using_scene_depth

In the code, when unprojecting depthmap into world point, we are using a positive z value(depth value). But in my understanding, ARKit uses right-handed coordinate system which means points with positive z value are behind the camera. So maybe we need to do some extra work to align the coordinate system(using `rotateToARCamera` matrix?). But I cannot understand why we need to flip both Y and Z plane.

```
static func makeRotateToARCameraMatrix(orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> matrix_float4x4 {
    // flip to ARKit Camera's coordinate
    let flipYZ = matrix_float4x4(
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, -1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, -1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1] )

    let rotationAngle = Float(cameraToDisplayRotation(orientation: orientation)) * .degreesToRadian
    return flipYZ * matrix_float4x4(simd_quaternion(rotationAngle, Float3(0, 0, 1)))
}
```

Update: I guess the key point is the coordinate system used for camera intrinsics matrix's pin-hole model has an inverse direction compared to the normal camera space in ARKit.

Answer (score 0):

Depth Map is a coordinate system where the Y coordinate is smaller at the top and larger at the bottom like image data, but ARKit is a coordinate system where the Y coordinate is smaller from the bottom and larger at the top.

For this reason, I think it is necessary to invert the Y coordinate.